# What is the simplest way to play a MIDI note for an indefinite duration in iOS?

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio, xcode5

I want to play instrument 49 in iOS for varying pitches [B2-E5] for varying durations.
I have been using the [Load Preset Demo](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/LoadPresetDemo/Listings/LoadPresetDemo_Classes_MainViewController_m.html) as reference.  The vibraphone.aupreset does not reference any files.  So, I had presumed that:

- I would be able to find and change the instrument in the aupreset file (unsuccessful so far)
- there is some way to tell the MIDI interface to turn notes on and off without generating *.mid files.

Here's what I did:

- Duplicated the audio related code from the proj
- removed the trombone related files and code (called `loadPresetTwo`: in place of `loadPresetOne:` in init (as opposed to `viewDidLoad`)),
- added a note sequence, and timer to turn off the previous note, and turn on the next note.
- Build.  Run.  I hear sound on the simulator.
- There is NO sound coming from my iPhone.

I have triple checked the code that I copied as well as where the calls are taking place.  It's all there.  The difference is the trombone related files and code are absent.  Perhaps there is some dependency that I'm not aware of.  Perhaps this is problem rooted in architectural differences between the simulator running on remote Mac VM and the iPhone.  Perhaps I can only speculate because I don't know enough about the problem to understand what questions to ask.

Any thoughts or suggested tests would be great!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[MusicPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/MusicPlayerServices_Reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/NewMusicPlayer) + [MusicSequence](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/MusicSequence_Reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009331-CH1-SW1) + [MusicTrack](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/MusicTrack_Reference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009332-CH2-DontLinkElementID_7) works.  It was much easier than trying to guess what code in the demo was doing.